# A phenomenon in which connection is possible through a hotspot, but cannot be connected through a regular wireless network

Tags: 22.04, laptop

I recently updated my Ubuntu laptop. (Thinkpad T14s gen2)
I just type `sudo apt update & upgrade` and reboot.
After that, my laptop couldn't access the internet through a wireless network.
Only I can access the internet through my cell phone's hotspot.

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       serial: **:**:**:**
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless fb
       configuration: broadcast=yes depth=32 driver=mt7921e driverversion=6.5.0-14-generic firmware=____010000-20220209150915 ip=192.168.58.29 latency=0 link=yes mode=1920x1080 multicast=yes visual=truecolor wireless=IEEE 802.11 xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:40-3f iomemory:40-3f iomemory:40-3f irq:94 memory:470200000-4702fffff memory:470300000-470303fff memory:470304000-470304fff
```

I am using ubuntu 22.04.
Is there any suspicious point?

Comment: Question is too broad, please edit the question to add enough detail to identify an adequate answer. See this helpful guide, and add the results of the debug commands to your question: "https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs"/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide